# jQuery change and modify ID attribute and fadeIn

Tags: jquery, variables, attributes, fadein

I've got a function that dynamically fades an element in based on the ID of the link you clicked. That is to say.. you click a link with an id of "show_tide" and the function drops "show_" from it and fades in what's left of the id. "show_tide" turns into "tide".

I'm having some kind of syntax error and can't figure out what it is.. help?

Thank you!

HTML:

```
<img id="show_tide" class="vid" src"#">
<iframe id="tide" class="vim" src="http://google.com"></iframe>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.vim, #underlay').hide();

$('.vid').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("show_","").toLowerCase();
    $('id, #underlay').fadeIn(400);
});

$('#underlay').click(function() {
    $('.vim, #underlay').fadeOut(400);
});
```

Comment: your javascript $('id, #underlay').fadeIn(400); is missing a css selector infront of the 'id' bit inside the selector. Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

line should be:

```
$('#' + id + ', #underlay').fadeIn(400);
```

otherwise you're trying to find all `<id>` elements :)

Comment: Don't forget the `'#'` in front of `id` ;-)

Comment: @box9No bueno. with or without the hash. :(